# Show local pdf inside webapplication [w/o remote server]

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, pdf.js

I'm developing a HTML5/.net POC in which I have a local HTML5 webapp shown inside a .net (C#) WebBrowser control.

The page is developed in asp.net MVC, downloaded as a single .htm file (using Chrome's SingleFile extension) and saved in a DB (or stored in a filesystem, doesn't matter), loaded and shown inside a .net webbrowser control.

[almost] Everything works: the page is rendered correctly, i can invoke js functions from C#, etc.

But now I have to show some pdf inline inside the page. The pdf is not served from a remote server (there's no server at all), but will be loaded from the filesystem (e.g. a temp file). The idea I have is to make a js function like showPdf(path, pageNum) in the html5 app and call it from .net.

The problem is that it looks there's no way (at least I couldn't find it) to load local pdf, both using Mozilla's pdf.js or  html tags, I get "Not allowed to load local resource" in Chrome console/"Access denied" alert in IE.

Is there some kind of component I can try/option I can set to allow the browser to load local pdfs?

The WebBrowser component uses IE to render the page, so maybe some kind of IE option/key registry I can change (the machines that will eventually use this webapp are known, we can configure them as we want)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to write here how I solved it: 
well, it was a webapp shown inside a WinForm WebBrowser control, so I used [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx) to call a C# method from JS. The C# method used the default OS pdf reader to show the pdf inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a traditional anchor element (`<a href="file:...">`) and then enable the [File Protocol Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#file_protocol_nav) feature control for your app.  (And, though it may seem obvious, it's probably worth confirming that IE feature controls do not to enable functionality in other browsers.)

I don't know that this would work, but it seems like a possible solution given the question.

Note that accessing file objects may permission to access local file system objects may be disabled by other policies or security measures.  More info/research may be needed.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance